# Как упростить вывод?

Tags: java, arraylist

Вывести arrayList в обратном порядке, а затем стереть.

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

Collections.reverse(arrayList);
System.out.println(arrayList);
arrayList.clear();
```

Как можно упростить?

Comment: Стереть что? Консоль не поддерживает стирание.

Comment: Может как то запихнуть в System.out.println(); разворот или развернуть другим методом

Comment: Как на самом деле гораздо проще сделать

Collections.reverse(arrayList);
System.out.println(arrayList);
arrayList.clear();  такой вопрос мне задали, уже час ломаю голову.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю сильно ли это упрощает, но можно через Stream API

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.stream()
            .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    list.clear();
```